# How does egg hatching distance relate to the hatched Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have different Pokémon eggs. One takes 10km to hatch, three take 5km, and the rest take 2km.

Which Pokémon can I get by hatching these eggs?

Comment: One hard thing to answer about this question is that the egg groups are changed ever once in a while and the pokemon in the egg is set at the time you get the egg.  So you have to look at when the egg was received and then look at the egg groups at that point.

Comment: Reminder to everyone answering this question to not hide information in images, and instead present it as text.

Comment: That's a good reminder. Makes it easier to edit posts in the future when the egg list changes

Answer (score 88, accepted):

All first evolution stage pokemon except for legendaries can appear. This is spread throughout the eggs as follows:

[image: Chart of egg distributions]

You cannot get any further evolution stages of pokemon from an egg, nor can you get a legendary from an egg.

These distances were minimum distances at the start, however, [that appears to have been fixed](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4wmkdt/ign_is_claiming_higher_km_eggs_have_the_potential/)

Comment: tl;dr, 10km has some really cool stuff

Comment: Except Eevee...if I get an Eevee from a 10k egg I will be very upset. He's already so common.

Comment: Note that all of the Pokémon in these categories are "at least" this much distance.  If you hatch a 10km egg you can get ANY of these Pokémon, while if you hatch a 2km egg, you can only get the ones on the left.

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj It's not wrong to require that distance to hatch an Eevee egg, because also in the main series they are hard to hatch.

Comment: @pinckerman sure but at least in those games I know an Eevee will come out and I won't waste time with him

Comment: is there a source on this?

Comment: @ChaseSandmann Important info, hopefully it'll be edited in.

Comment: @pinckerman You can't catch Eevees in the wild in the games though.

Comment: @CaptainMan I've caught several eevees in the wild

Comment: @CaptainMan You actually can in BW2, XY and ORAS.

Comment: Guess I am an old fart then.

Comment: The good thing about hatching an Eevee is all the Eevee candy. I hatch and immediately evolved into a Jolteon. So to me it was like hatching a Jolteon.

Comment: I downvoted this because it simply isn't true. Just yesterday I got two eevees from two separate 2km eggs. Maybe you can get them from 10km eggs too, but this chart is definitely misleading.

Comment: @nasukkin, you don't even get downvote privileges till 125 rep.

Comment: Every source I've found corroborates this chart. If you can provide proof, I will take appropriate action. As it stands now, however, I will go by what information I have.

Comment: @Unionhawk I'm not sure how to provide more concrete proof. AFAIK, the game doesn't record what kind of egg a pokemon hatched from, does it? All I know is that I have yet to find a 10km egg, but that I have hatched Eevees. Also, is it possible that egg-results are dependant on the poke-stop region you get the egg from? FWIW, most of my eggs have been from stops around the San Francisco Bay Area.

Comment: Does anyone know why the hell *Onix* is hatched from a *10km* egg? That's whack.

Comment: I won't validate the guy who thinks he got Eevee from 2kms, but I will say that Mr. Mime is *absolutely* a 10km 'mon, and this is a frequently noted inaccuracy. His placement in the 5km category was originally *conjecture* due to the fact that other region-exclusives hatch from 5kms.

Comment: @Isuka I am aware of these differences, and will update the image later today

Comment: I'm going to get this answer up-to-date later today to make sure the top-voted accepted answer is updated.

Answer (score 22):

### 2 KILOMETERS

- Bulbasaur
- Charmander
- Squirtle
- Caterpie
- Weedle
- Pidgey
- Rattata
- Spearow
- Zubat
- Geodude
- Magikarp
- Cleffa
- Igglybuff

### 5 KILOMETERS

- Ekans
- Sandshrew
- Nidoran(f)
- Nidoran(m)
- Vulpix
- Oddish
- Paras
- Venonat
- Meowth
- Psyduck
- Mankey
- Growlithe
- Poliwag
- Abra
- Machop
- Bellsprout
- Tentacool
- Ponyta
- Slowpoke
- Magnemite
- Farfetch'd
- Doduo
- Seel
- Grimer
- Shellder
- Gastly
- Drowzee
- Krabby
- Voltorb
- Exeggute
- Cubone
- Lickitung
- Koffing
- Rhyhorn
- Tangela
- Kangaskhan
- Horsea
- Goldeen
- Staryu
- Mr. Mime
- Tauros
- Porygon
- Togepi
- Pichu

### 10 KILOMETERS

- Onix
- Hitmonlee
- Hitmonchan
- Chansey
- Scyther
- Pinsir
- Lapras
- Eevee
- Omanyte
- Kabuto
- Aerodactyl
- Snorlax
- Dratini
- Magby
- Smoochum
- Elekid

Comment: This answer is outdated

Answer (score 17):

I've found an updated version of what you get for every 2k, 5k, 7k and 10k egg.

You can also view the updated eggs on the Silph Road [here](https://thesilphroad.com/egg-distances)

I plan to keep this answer updated when the eggs change.

**Feb 1 2019**

- Taillow added to 2k eggs
- Lileep, Anorith, Feebas, Beldum, Nincada, Absol, Mawile removed from 7k eggs

[image]

**Jan 16 2019**

[image]

---

**Update**

The eggs change so frequently that it's difficult to keep up with replacing the answer here. So please refer to the [Silph Road](https://thesilphroad.com/egg-distances) for the updated list.

Comment: 7km eggs can also include Alolan Rattata and Alolan Geodude, in addition to the Pokemon pictured.

Comment: if I had the time, I'd add them in for you. :) I figured adding them in as a comment was better than nothing!

Answer (score 8):

In conjunction to the other answers, it does appear that you can get 2km Pokémon from 5 or 10km eggs and 5km Pokémon from 10 km eggs. A number of people have stated that they have gotten lower tier Pokémon from higher tier eggs. Here are a few such examples.

- A Mr. Mime from a 10 km egg. ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sa18o/eggs_hatchlings_sorted_by_distance_credit_to/d57pjfk), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sa18o/eggs_hatchlings_sorted_by_distance_credit_to/d57szt5), [3](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sa18o/eggs_hatchlings_sorted_by_distance_credit_to/d57u90l), [4](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sa18o/eggs_hatchlings_sorted_by_distance_credit_to/d57vldn))
- A Pikachu from a 5 km egg. ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sa18o/eggs_hatchlings_sorted_by_distance_credit_to/d57op5p))
- A Magikarp from a 5 km egg. ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sa18o/eggs_hatchlings_sorted_by_distance_credit_to/d57vq67))
- A Magikarp from a 10 km egg. ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sa18o/eggs_hatchlings_sorted_by_distance_credit_to/d57rynv))
- A Bulbasuar from a 10 km egg. ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sa18o/eggs_hatchlings_sorted_by_distance_credit_to/d57xd3k))
- A Zubat from a 5 km egg. ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sa18o/eggs_hatchlings_sorted_by_distance_credit_to/d57vrij), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sa18o/eggs_hatchlings_sorted_by_distance_credit_to/d57tnoq))
- A Weedle from a 10 km egg. ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sa18o/eggs_hatchlings_sorted_by_distance_credit_to/d57zwpk))
- A Charmander from a 5 km egg. ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sa18o/eggs_hatchlings_sorted_by_distance_credit_to/d57s6d7))
- A Nidoran from a 10 km egg. ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sa18o/eggs_hatchlings_sorted_by_distance_credit_to/d57t33u))

Given that so many people have reported this happening, it appears that there are tiers of Pokémon from eggs, however lower tier Pokémon can be hatched from higher tier eggs.

This picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj9Fy.jpg) depicts these tiers.

Comment: Yeah, all of the exceptions I've heard (except for one) have been lower distance hatched from higher.

Comment: That's... unfortunate. Now we need "I walked 10 km and all I got was this stupid Caterpie" t-shirts.

Comment: This answer is outdated

Answer (score 4):

As of the Generation II release, the egg tiers have been changed up quite a bit.

A full list can be seen on [this site](https://pokemongohub.net/generation-2/pokemon-go-generation-ii-egg-chart/).

Someone converted this chart to image format [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6m1J.jpg):

[image: visual of egg tiers (sorry no pictures :( )]

---

### Notable Gen I Pokémon Egg tier changes:

#### From 5km to 2km:

- Abra
- Bellsprout
- Diglett
- Ekans
- Exeggcute
- Gastly
- Goldeen
- Krabby
- Machop
- Nidoran F/M
- Oddish
- Slowpoke
- Venonat

#### From 10km to 5km:

- Elekid*
- Kabuto
- Lickitung
- Magby*
- Omanyte
- Onix
- Pinsir
- Porygon
- Scyther
- Smoochum*
- Tangela
- Tyrogue*

*These are Gen II pre-evolutions that replaced their parents in the egg pools but also switched tiers

Comment: This answer is outdated

Answer (score 3):

This list is presented first in order of egg-hatching distance and then alphabetical order, made using the lists from [SilphRoad](https://thesilphroad.com/egg-distances) and [GamePress](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/pokemon-go-eggs-list):

**2 KM eggs**

- Abra
- Aron
- Barboach
- Bellsprout
- Bidoof
- Gastly
- Kricketot
- Luvdisc
- Machop
- Magikarp
- Misdreavus
- Nidoran (both genders)
- Poocyhena
- Slowpoke
- Spheal
- Starly
- Swablu
- Swinub
- Taillow
- Wailmer
- Zubat

**5 KM eggs**

- Anorith
- Bulbasaur
- Buneary
- Cacnea
- Carvanha
- Charmander
- Chikorita
- Chimchar
- Chinchou
- Croagunk
- Cyndaquil
- Duskull
- Eevee
- Electrike
- Gligar
- Growlithe
- Horsea
- Houndour
- Lickitung
- Lileep
- Lotad
- Magnemite
- Meditite
- Mudkip
- Nosepass
- Onix
- Phanphy
- Pineco
- Pinsir
- Piplup
- Poliwag
- Ponyta
- Sandshrew
- Scyther
- Seedot
- Shuckle
- Sneasel
- Snorunt
- Snover
- Squirtle
- Stunky
- Tangela
- Torchic
- Totodile
- Treecko
- Turtwig
- Yanma

**7 KM – this includes Alolan forms (minus Rattata), baby Pokemon, and a few other Hoenn Pokemon**

- Absol
- Alolan Diglett
- Alolan Geodude
- Alolan Grimer
- Alolan Meowth
- Alolan Sandshrew
- Alolan Vuplix
- Anorith
- Azurill
- Beldum
- Budew
- Chingling
- Cleffa
- Elekid
- Feebas
- Igglybuff
- Lileep
- Magby
- Mantyke
- Mawile
- Munchlax
- Nincada
- Pichu
- Riolu
- Smoochum
- Togepi
- Tyrogue
- Wynaut

**10 KM**

- Aerodactyl
- Bagon
- Beldum
- Dratini
- Drifloon
- Feebas
- Larvitar
- Mareep
- Porygon
- Ralts
- Riolu
- Shinx
- Skorupi
- Slakoth
- Trapinch

Some Pokemon that can hatch from 7km eggs can also hatch from a 5km or 10km egg: they are Anorith & Lileep (5km) and Beldum & Riolu (7km).

Answer (score -1):

From what I've seen so far, there doesn't appear to be any strict limits on which Pokemon can appear in varying distance eggs. For example, I've gotten a Weedle in both 2.0 and 10.0 kilometer eggs.

However, I seem to get less common Pokemon from the longer distance eggs.

Comment: So.. you are saying you could get the same pokemon _whether_ you have a 2km or 10km egg, right? scnr

Comment: @Andrew That is correct. You could always get anything from a 2k egg

Comment: If you got a Weedle from a 10km egg, you got hosed.

Comment: Probably time to start reversing the vote total on this answer.