# Do I accumulate candies from eggs in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I just got a Dratini from 10km egg. I got 22 candies with it. If I get another Dratini from a 10km egg will I have 44 candies?

Comment: Candies you got from egg is random in quantity, but you will always get candies for pokemon tree you got.

Comment: @NamikazeSheena You should post this as an answer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Yes, we can say multiple.**

**1. Multiple Candies** As have been already commented, candies got from hatched egg is randomly given from  [3 up to 35 candies](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/gaming/what-to-play/pokemon-go-candy-what-is-it-how-do-i-use-it-where-do-i-find-it/). In your example, you got 22 *Dratini Candies*, and hatching another might be different.

**2. "Rare" pokemons** There are pokemons that are spawning rarely in general context. And some of these pokemon that might be rare to you (or not) can be found on the eggs, which differ according to category by miles, 2km, 5km and 10km.

[image]

Comment: How do you fit a Snorlax in an egg? :D

Comment: @Songo the same way you fit one in a poke ball!

Comment: Minor sidenote - the plural of "Pokemon" is typically "Pokemon", not "Pokemons".

Comment: @Amadeus9 There are probably more pokemon go players than there have been pokemon players in the past.  As such, through the power of numbers, the plural of pokemon is whatever the new wave says it is...  Me, I'm lobbying for "pokemii".

Comment: @Yakk That's probably true, and I think that's great, but who's more likely to change their preferred pluralization: the gently-corrected newcomer, or the veteran expert who just sees people saying it wrong?

Comment: @amadeus9 that is why the corrcet spelling is pokemii.  Glad you agree!

Comment: @Yakk actually Nintendo(/Game Freak/The Pokemon Company) decides.

Comment: @Nacht but in the famous case of "GIF v JIF" the creator said it was JIF when everyone just says GIF. In my opinion you call it whatever you want as long as it is a relevant word (ie: pokemii, pokemons, pokemon, etc)

Comment: @songo same way you hatch an egg into an exeggcute (6 eggs) or a ghastly (ghost)

Answer (score 2):

Your total number of Dratini candies will be an accumulation (a sum) of all your Dratini candy rewards.

The number of candies you get from an egg is random (between some limits).

So if you

- get a Dratini (which is [one of 17](http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/eggs.shtml) 10km egg Pokémon: ~6% minus an unkown percentage because you can get lower level Pokémon from eggs - see comments - so I'll halve it: ~3%) and
- it will give you [3-35](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/gaming/what-to-play/pokemon-go-candy-what-is-it-how-do-i-use-it-where-do-i-find-it/) Dratini candies (it should be random distributed : ~3%,)
- and if you haven't get other candies from catching

than you will have 44 Dratini Candies (at ~0.1%).

Comment: You can get lower level Pokemon from higher level eggs, so it's not 1/17, it's 1/however many Pokemon can be hatched.

Comment: @Kat I haven't seen evidence of that; 5km eggs hatch 5km pokemon, 10km eggs hatch 10km pokemon for me.  The sucky ones, for sure (I'm looking at you, Onyx), but still.

Comment: @Joe See the answers on this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274373/which-pok%C3%A9mon-can-appear-by-hatching I've also personally received lots of 2 km Pokemon from 5 km eggs. You're very lucky if you've never run into it!

Comment: @Kat Interesting.  I have only had 2 10km eggs, so small sample size I guess...

Comment: Ok, seems that there is a smaller possibility to get lower level egg Pokémon. I received an equivalent Pokémon for each egg. I'll add this to the answer.