# Are eggs sorted in specific order and what determines it?

Tags: pokemon-go

So I have a lot of eggs and I found out that they are stored in some strange order. 
[image: Picture 1]

On this picture, I just got 2km egg from Pokestop. You can see that it is 4th in order.

**My concern is, what determines in which order they are seen there?**

Obvious thing is that the **ones in incubator** are **always first**, but then the rest is sorted by some hidden value, because it is obvious, that they are not sorted by distance needed nor time of acquisition.

According to some [rumours](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/280932/are-eggs-predetermined-before-you-hatch-them), there MIGHT be the thing that eggs are predetermined by time you get them. So...

Is it possible that those are ordered by

- Level of pokémon they will hatch
- ID of pokémon they will hatch
- or just by some random seed they are using (if any is used)?

I know that I will need to hatch them all eventually, but if we can know what ones can yield better pokémons, we can hatch in some order that eventually can benefit to get the better pokémons after all (or faster). If the order is determined by the level when I got them, then hatching first the eggs with lower level can clear my inventory to get better eggs and similar.

I also found the table included [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274373/which-pok%C3%A9mon-can-appear-by-hatching/274381#274381) that shows which pokémon can be hatched from which egg and there are some overlaps (higher pokémon ID from lower egg), so that table is not against the possibility of order-by pokémon ID, preserving the possibility of misorder (by distance) in inventory.

To add, I have another screenshot, since the first one, I already hatched the in-progress 5km one, then did 2km egg, then I started to hatch one 5km egg (I think) from first line. You can see that I got another 5km egg that is sitting between 10km eggs.

[image: Picture 2]

I know that there might be no exact answer, because we probably cannot access the code, but there are communities that do incredible research and if there is possibility to get the answer for this, it can benefit a lot of players to hatch on demand. (For example the latter stored 2km egg, the higher chance for Magicarp, if stored by ID etc.)

Comment: I got a Weedle from a new 2 km egg, which was in the middle of the list, before I incubated it and a Rattata from an equally old egg, which was at the bottom. So I'd say its safe to disregard the age and ID theories.

Comment: I think the order of ***non-incubated*** eggs depends on age and ***incubated*** eggs will always be placed before the non-incubated eggs

Comment: @PythonMaster my screens and text show that newly acquired eggs are placed in the middle of the rest of eggs, so that is not the thing. Also that Incuated ones are first is obvious.

Comment: I just hatched a low level 5 km egg which was situated in the middle of the pack.  My best guess is for semi-random ordering.  When the app is launched and your game data is initializing, the eggs are placed in an unordered list, which lacks any ordering priority yet is not equivalent to an active, random ordering.  That particular ordering will persist until the app's cache is removed, such as killing the app.  Even with unordered lists, if the items are static, some orderings are more likely to occur since the system processes the list in the same way each time.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have experienced the only order of eggs is whether or not they're currently incubated (and their chronological order), since they're on top of the list. The rest is most likely random.

The (non-incubating egg's) order might even change when you pick another egg to incubate or get one to fill an open slot. This leaves only two possibilities:

- Random order
- Fixed order, but this means the setting determining the sorting order changes when you start a new incubation (contained Pokémon for example) ...which is very unlikely. 
  This would mean, if they're sorted by ID the contained Pokémon changes every time the amount of eggs changes. Or the IV, or Level, etc. To be honest, that would be stupid programming since they'd be trying to randomize the order and could simply use a pure randomizing algorithm instead.